# How can I install phalcon (or any custom PHP module/extension) on my shared cPanel web host?

Tags: php

Is it possible to install **[phalcon](http://phalconphp.com/)** (a custom PHP PECL extension/module) on a shared web hosting service that uses **cPanel**, or is it normally something that requires root access?

That is, can I still somehow get the benefits of phalcon on my existing host without having to rent a VPS?

Comment: While I certainly appreciate your QA here, it's off-topic for Serverfault. Perhaps it would be more appropriate at Stackoverflow or webmasters.SE.

Comment: Hi @EEAA, apologies if it was miscategorized.  Are cPanel questions not suitable for ServerFault?  Since it's not specifically a programming question, I thought the draconian mods at StackOverflow would be even less likely to accept it.  Can it be migrated to Webmasters.SE?  Or do I need to copy & paste it?

Comment: Five people closed the thread without responding to my question.  Thank you.  * frown *

Comment: thanks for posting and answering this, it being closed is a fine example of the elitism here that is complained about by various users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your web host *may* install custom extensions for you, it can't hurt to ask.

But most, generally, will recommend you upgrade to a VPS which allows you full root access, the ability to install anything you want, and less risk that you will negatively impact performance for other users of the server.  VPSs can require extra administration effort and technical knowledge unless you opt for a "Managed VPS" which usually adds a significant monthly cost.

And so, assuming my host would not want to enable a custom extension for me, I set out to discover if I could do it on my own.  I found a way of doing so **without even needing SSH or command-line access**.

### Step 1: Obtain phalcon.so

You need to obtain the correct build of `phalcon.so` for your server environment and version of PHP.

cPanel generally runs on  CentOS, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), or CloudLinux. The phalcon site offers some binary versions for download, but sadly nothing for CentOS/RHEL.

Here are the files I compiled for CentOS 64bit with PHP 5.3 and 5.4.  You're welcome to try that if you like until others make binaries available, or see below for instructions on how to compile your own.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9911892/phalcon/1.3.2/PHP5.3/phalcon.so
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9911892/phalcon/1.3.2/PHP5.4/phalcon.so

Upload this via FTP to your home directory.

### Step 2: Enable the extension

You need to add the following line to `php.ini`:

```
extension = /home/__USERNAME__/phalcon.so
```

(Replace __USERNAME__ with your actual cPanel username)

I'm not sure whether all cPanel hosts are like this, but my host [VentraIP](http://www.ventraip.com.au/) allows you to put a custom `php.ini` or `.user.ini` file in your `public_html` folder which overrides the default PHP settings.

You can get a hint at whether this is possible by uploading `<?php phpinfo();` to a file on your server and call it from your browser.  Hopefully you'll have a line like the one below...

[image: custom PHP.ini file]

Otherwise you might have to use `.user.ini` files which are shown like this...

[image: .user.ini file PHP]

Note that with `.user.ini` files, these are commonly cached by the server for 300 seconds, so if you make a change to one, it may take up to 5 minutes for the change to take effect.

### Step 3: Verify that it works

Refresh your `phpinfo()` page in the browser.  If phalcon has loaded correctly, you will find an additional section displayed that looks like this:

[image: phalcon phpinfo extension enabled]

If you've got this far, hooray!

### Not working?

Enable error logging by adding `error_log = /home/__USERNAME__/error.log` to your `php.ini` or `.user.ini` and refresh the `phpinfo()` file.  Then check the log or any obvious errors.  If you're not getting any error and phalcon is not showing up, then it's likely that your server is not reading your ini file correctly.  Is it definitely in your `public_html` folder?  Have you tried both `php.ini` and `.user.ini` formats?

On my first try I started getting this error appearing in my logs:
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/yumpstag/phalcon.so' - /home/yumpstag/phalcon.so: undefined symbol: output_globals in Unknown on line 0`

I found out that I had the wrong version of `phalcon.so` (built for PHP 5.3 instead of 5.4) and so had to recompile it.

### How to compile phalcon.so (or another extension) yourself

Chances are, you won't be able to run a compiler on your cPanel server without root access, so you'll need to find a similar server to do this on.  Here's what I did:

- [Downloaded a CentOS 6 VirtualBox image from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualboximage/files/CentOS/6.0/CentOS-6-x86_64.7z/download) (or [see the full list here](http://virtualboxes.org/images/centos/))
- Boot it up in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Login with root / reverse
- (If some keyboard characters aren't showing up right, type `loadkeys us`)

The next step is to ensure you have the correct major version of PHP installed, **this needs to match what you're using on your cPanel web host**.  If you want a different version of PHP other than the default that CentOS supports (PHP 5.3 at the time of writing), try this:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
sudo yum install php54w-devel        # FOR PHP 5.4 ONLY
```

(Otherwise, to go with the CentOS default version:)

```
sudo yum install php-devel           # FOR PHP 5.3 ONLY
```

Then install the remaining prerequisites:

```
sudo yum install php-mysql gcc libtool git
```

Fetch phalcon and compile:

```
git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

Once it has finished, it will tell you where the phalcon.so file is.  You can then upload that via FTP to your cPanel home directory.

```
sudo yum install ftp
ftp myhostname.com
put /usr/lib64/php/modules/phalcon.so /phalcon.so
```

Then go back to steps 2 and 3 to complete the process.

Hope that helps some others.  Please comment below if you have any additional tips to offer.

Comment: Why did you answer your own question? Is this a posting like "hey world look what I know"?

Comment: Hi @deagh, yes, doing so is encouraged.  See here:  http://serverfault.com/help/self-answer

Comment: thx for the link and... good job ;)

Comment: I also found another blog post which documents a very similar thing on their host HostGator.  That may also help some:  http://wpmarketing.org/2013/09/phalcon-php-framework-on-hostgator-shared-hosting-account/

Comment: just a note for future attempts, if you want to identify the correct centos version your host runs, look at top of phpinfo() output titled "System": 2.6.32-531.23.3.lve1.2.66.el6.x86_64 from the start of this you can get the kernel version and architecture and then match it against the list at wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS#CentOS_releases (click show)